# Argument 1 passed to app\Controllers\Controller::__construct() must be an instance of Interop\Container\ContainerInterface

Tags: php, slim-3

Slim Application Error

```
    The application could not run because of the following error:
    Details
    Type:TypeError
    Message:Argument 1 passed to app\Controllers\Controller::__construct() must be an instance of Interop\Container\ContainerInterface, instance of Slim\Container given, called in
        /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php on line 102
```

I am getting this error when call any method.Other controllers extend  this controller 
Controller.php file looks like this-

```
<?php

namespace app\Controllers;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface as ContainerInterface;

abstract class Controller
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function __get($property)
    {
        if($this->container->{$property})
        {
            return $this->container->{$property};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you plz show us your code so we could look?

Answer (score 0):

[`Slim\Container`](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Container.php) is implementing directly `Psr\Container\ContainerInterface` instead of the interface from [deprecated interlop package](http://www.slimframework.com/2019/11/28/slim-3.12.3-release.html). Your constructor should change typehint to the PSR version too.

Comment: @Arati What version of slim do you have?

Comment: I have slim 3.12 version

Comment: @Arati Maybe you have a wrong typehint in a different class extending from your abstract controller? (I see your controller in the question is abstract. - This would by itself throw a different error.)
I've created a simple working POC:
https://gist.github.com/Yrwein/dce2c81c3ac9df5c3a8d0b92211ba8c3